# How to compare user input with string getting from process.stdin.on()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

When I'm trying to compare a string with an input from process.stdin.on , I'm getting false always.

**//Imagine user inputting 'hello' always.**

```
process.stdin.on('data', userInput => {
  let text = userInput.toString();
  if(text == 'hello'){
    console.log("True");
  }
  if(text === 'hello'){
    console.log("True");
  }
  process.exit();
});
```

> If I check typeof userInput it shows  string.  If i log userInput it
> shows exact the same as my string.

so, why these conditions are false?

Comment: Not sure about your backend, but console.log(text) would be my first step to debug it, so you know what you actually fetched and if it is indeed "hello" as expected... maybe you got some spaces or linebreaks in the input by accident, you'll never know unless you log it.
Also there is really no need for the second if...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user input includes the end-of-line markers, for example `"\r\n"` in Windows (but this might be `"\n"` on other systems). So you must check whether `text === "hello\r\n"`.

Alternatively, you can let [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/readline.html) split the user input into lines for you:

```js
readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin})
.on("line", text => {
  if(text === 'hello')
    console.log("True");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative , you could use openStdin with a listener

```
const stdin = process.openStdin();
stdin.addListener("data", function(d) {
    const text = d.toString().trim();
    console.log("you entered: [" + d.toString().trim() + "]");
    if (text == 'hello') {
        console.log("True");
    }
    if (text === 'hello') {
        console.log("True");
    }
});
```